# Make a service call at regular interval of time in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am new to swift programming and I don't know how to call a method at regular interval of time. I have a demo app for service call but i don't know how can i call it at regular interval of time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create an object of NSTimer() and call a function on definite time interval like this:

```
var updateTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(15.0, target: self, selector: "callFunction", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

this will call callFunction() every 15 sec.

```
func callFunction(){
    print("function called")
}
```

Comment: Note that the timer will pause when the app goes in background.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple example with start and stop functions:

```
private let kTimeoutInSeconds:NSTimeInterval = 60

private var timer: NSTimer?

func startFetching() {
  self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(kTimeoutInSeconds,
    target:self,
    selector:Selector("fetch"),
    userInfo:nil,
    repeats:true)
}

func stopFetching() {
  self.timer!.invalidate()
}

func fetch() {
  println("Fetch called!")
}
```

If you get an `unrecognized selector` exception, **make sure your class inherits from NSObject or else the timer's selector won't find the function!**

Answer (score 2):

**Timer variant with a block (iOS 10, Swift 4)**

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    print("I am called every 5 seconds")
}
```

Do not forget call `invalidate` method

```
timer.invalidate()
```

**GCD approach (will tend to drift a bit late over time)**

```
func repeatMeWithGCD() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 5) {
        print("I am called every 5 seconds")

        self.repeatMeWithGCD()//recursive call
    }
}
```

Do not forget to create a return condition to prevent stackoverflow error